# domxml new doc function issue in php

Tags: php, html, xml

Actually,i'm using google map locator i required domxml new doc function so how will create this function please help me how to resolve this issue.
     my issue like :Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc() in on line 58

here my code:

```
 require("db_connection.php");

    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
    $node = $doc->create_element("tbl_master_property");
    $parnode = $doc->append_child($node);

    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
      die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
      die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select all the rows in the markers table
    $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      // Add to XML document node
      $node = $doc->create_element("tbl_master_property");
      $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);

      $newnode->set_attribute("id", $row['id']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
      $newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
    }

    $xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();
    echo $xmlfile;
```

Comment: Where did you find reference to `domxml_new_doc` function? It seems to be from PHP 4 and is listed in the `Deprecated functions` list in the manual

Comment: yaa i'm using version php5

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` instead

Comment: after  i'm using 'm getting this issue like : Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::append_child()

Comment: You are also using the deprecated `mysql` api - use `mysqli` or `PDO`. The method for DOMDocument is `appendChild`

Comment: it's `DOMNode::appendChild`

Comment: yaa i changed that now it is showing issue sir like: This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mysqli` and `DOMDocument` you should be able to do the same with the following - though it's not tested.

```
<?php

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $sql='select * from `markers`;';
    $result=$db->query( $sql );

    $attribs=array('id','name','address','lat','lng','type');


    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
    $dom->formatOutput=true;
    $dom->standalone=true;
    $dom->recover=true;

    $root=$dom->createElement('tbl_master_property');
    $dom->appendChild( $root );


    while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){
        $node=$dom->createElement('property');
        $root->appendChild( $node );

        foreach( $attribs as $attrib ){
            $attr = $dom->createAttribute( $attrib );
            $value= $dom->createTextNode( $rs->$attrib );
            $attr->appendChild( $value );
            $node->appendChild( $attr );
        }
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/xml");
    echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method DOMDocument::apendChild()`

Comment: Just write `$dom=new DOMDocument('1.0');`

Comment: i changed all the my code now also showing issue like :Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::apendChild()

Comment: see comment above - fixed in code snippet, it was hastily written with not enough coffee in my veins

Comment: this is my changes code please check it: $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $root=$dom->createElement('tbl_master_property');
    $dom->apendChild($root); again showing issue like :
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::apendChild()

Comment: it should be `appendChild` not `apendChild` that was a simple typo due to writing it too quickly - the above code has been fixed

Comment: Sir, i need show google map locator how will show please help me

Comment: i stored my data for (name , address ,lat,lng) how to get and how to show the locator in google map please help

Comment: i'm using this code please check it once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110899/how-to-show-google-maps-with-multiple-locations-and-many-markers-in-php?noredirect=1#comment83197348_48110899